# Ubuntu Minimal Install mounts internal HD as sdb

Tags: boot, system-installation, mount, ssd, mbr

I am trying to setup 13.04 on a new internal SSD on an Intel NUC i3 from a USB Stick.  For some reason during the install it mounts the SSD as sdb and installs on it but writes the MBR to the USB Stick (mounted as sda). So if I try to boot without the SD after the install completes it cannot find the OS since it is looking on sda.  I looked in the bios to see if anything is in there but nothing jumped out at me.

This has not happened on other PCs. I tried doing complete wipes of both the ssd and usb drive MBRs which made no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest fixes are the best.  Just pull the usb stick after the first screen off the install process as it is no longer needed since everything is in memory...

Edit: this is no longer true *automatically*, however, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829917/can-i-boot-a-live-usb-fully-to-ram-allowing-me-to-remove-the-disk/829962#829962) for how to make the USB boot fully to RAM.