# Can I boot a Live USB fully to RAM, allowing me to remove the disk?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, live-usb

I have a live USB made with the standard Ubuntu disk image creator for 16.04 LTS. In the current state, I can boot to this disk, but it still requires the original USB to run properly at all times.

Attempting to pull the drive and use the system generates a large amount of I/O errors, further suggesting that the USB drive is actually needed for things not *already* loaded into RAM (For example, Firefox worked without the USB, but I used it once before already. `apt`, on the other hand, did not.)

Is there a way to copy the entire Ubuntu live disk to RAM, so I can remove the drive and free up a USB slot for other things?

Comment: Did you try the "toram" kernel parameter?  That will at least speed things up after the boot, not sure if you can remove the USB.

Comment: @ubfan1 I have not yet, I can test later today, though.

Comment: On a similar note I want justify a 16gb update when I only use 2 to 3 gb of 8 gb now. If I can through all of Ubuntu into ram (excluding Home) that would be sweet. That 2 second SSD lag would cut down to .25 seconds. Call me spoiled  :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distro that I can load into RAM?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28671/distro-that-i-can-load-into-ram)

Comment: **Can Ubuntu be installed to the pendrive it was booted from?** https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You simply need to add the `toram` boot parameter in GRUB.

Here is how you can do that, tested (and screenshots taken) with an Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit desktop iso in a VM:

#### Boot in UEFI mode

Boot from the live DVD/USB and wait for the GRUB menu to appear.

[image]

Highlight `Try Ubuntu without installing` using <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> and then press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the boot script.

[image]

Search for the line starting with `linux` and add the option `toram` right after (or instead of) `quiet splash`, as depicted above. Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the modified script.

After Ubuntu has fully booted, you may eject/unmount the live DVD/USB device and continue using the system and all available programs.

#### Boot in BIOS/Legacy mode

Boot from the live DVD/USB and wait for the language selection boot menu to appear.

[image]

Select your language with <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> and confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The boot menu appears.

[image]

Use <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> to highlight `Try Ubuntu without installing`.

To make the editable `Boot Options` line appear, press <kbd>F6</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the little pop-up.

Then you can navigate the cursor in the `Boot Options` line using <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>. Search the `quiet splash` options and add the `toram` option after or instead of them, as depicted above.

Boot the modified configuration by simply pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After Ubuntu has fully booted, you may eject/unmount the live DVD/USB device and continue using the system and all available programs.

Comment: Unfortunately as I confirmed in my recent post, this is NOT how the toram parameter works. It does not in any way allow removing the disk without issues. I'm trying to work through how to do just this here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449132 (Just to note: I'm using 22.04, both with and without persistent enabled. This option may have worked for this purpose previously, but now it does not help)

Comment: @Pecacheu I just used Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS in a VM and the `toram` worked perfectly and loaded completely into RAM and I was able to remove the ISO file before it completed loading to the desktop without any errors.  So this still works just fine and this answer it still correct.

Comment: [Here's a great tutorial](https://calvin.me/create-persistent-ubuntu-16-04-live-usb-even-boots-ram/) on how to make a persistent live USB using `mkusb`, and on how to permanently edit the live USB's grub boot menu to add an option to always boot to RAM! See the section at the end titled "Extra: Boot the Live USB to RAM".

Comment: Note: I just tested the instructions in this answer on an Ubuntu 22.04 live USB, booted on an old 2015 MacBook with 8 GB RAM, and they worked great! After booting, without loading anything else, the total RAM used was **5.1 GB** (62.5% in my case), so be sure to have at least 8 GB of RAM for this to work! In the file manager after fully booting I was then able to right-click the USB and choose to eject it, then I removed it fully and the OS still kept running just fine!