# restoring files with only 2 USB ports machine

Tags: usb, hard-drive, data-recovery, ethernet, hfs+

I want to recover my Files from a 1TB Hard Disk with HFS+ File System.
I can't recover my files using mac version commercial tools and I can't see the lost files using macOS.

I have a macBook Air with only 2 USB ports.

1. The External USB Hard Drive. (It will be the source of files to be recovered)
2. The USB with Ubuntu 17 (Live) I see the Files!!!

**And the Drive/Hard Disk Destiny for recovered files ?**

*NOTE*: My MacBook's HD haven't space.
I have old 32 bits (x86) Machine with Windows 7 (without space) but Enough USB ports.

**What is the recommended alternative to establish a destiny to copy my recovered files?**

`dd` **command work in LAN network environment?**

Comment: can't you use a usb hub to provide more usb ports?    as to copying files, I'd use `scp` (secure-copy; or a secure version of `rcp` (remote-copy)) myself to copy to another machine with space.

Comment: Well just install Ubuntu. ;-) The obvious solution here would be to use a USB hub – or your Windows machine. What's the problem with that?

Comment: I was thinking the speed or performance of the hub. Another is to boot  ubuntu 64 from network (how from Windows 32?)

Comment: You can also copy your Ubuntu Live System to RAM and run it without a medium, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/829962/507051) for instructions. More lightweight distros like Puppy Linux might be (even) better for that.

Comment: the `dd` command can output to any target on your filesystem. As long as you've mounted the network drive properly and have write permission, virtually any program providing output can write there whether by output file or redirection. In the case of `dd` your output will be an image file so @guiverc suggestion is likely to better fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

### Install Ubuntu into the target drive

One alternative is to install Ubuntu into the target drive, the Drive/Hard Disk Destiny for recovered files.

- You can install Ubuntu like into an internal drive (but to this external drive, connected to one of the two USB ports).
- You can also create a persistent live Ubuntu in this this external drive, connected to one of the two USB ports.

Then you can boot Ubuntu from the target drive and copy from the source drive.

The following links describe how this can be done,

- [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

### Backup

Installing an operating system is risky. Even if you think, that the files on the target drive will survive, they may disappear. So you should **backup everything that you cannot afford to lose** from the target drive before you start installing.

Answer (score 0):

Power up your old windows machine with ubuntu live usb inserted and boot up ubuntu. Connect your external HDDs and copy the required files using ubuntu.

Comment: is there difference between 32 bits and 64 bits ubuntu?

Comment: @ChepeQuestn 64-bit needs to have 64-bit CPU, 32-bit just needs an x86 (standard) CPU. Also, 32-bit has a limitation to 4 GB of RAM and will be smaller.

Comment: You can also prepare 32bit ubuntu live usb.