# FirmwareTestSuiteLive : How I can run the live image from ram?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, filesystem, initramfs

On this [official page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FirmwareTestSuite/FirmwareTestSuiteLive), the image can be run from USB. But my requirement is that the image can be run from RAM after copied from USB.

And I know the way to boot the Live USB to RAM for Ubuntu 16.04 image: hit the <kbd>E</kbd> key to edit the boot options of Ubuntu. Add the word `toram` between `quiet` and `boot=casper`, then hit <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot and save options.

Refer to this page: [Can I boot a Live USB fully to RAM, allowing me to remove the disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829917/can-i-boot-a-live-usb-fully-to-ram-allowing-me-to-remove-the-disk)

I do the same work on the FWTS live image, but no effect at all. The image always runs on USB. My expectation is everything is copied from USB to RAM. I want to remove the USB and continue using the system and all available programs.

It's very critical to me! Can anyone help me?

Comment: I try to correct as much as possible your post, confirm it to me (or [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1189729/edit) it if I misunderstand correctly your question)

Comment: File a feature request https://launchpad.net/fwts-live As you used the same method user with a normal live session I would claim "toram" is not supported.