# I wanna run Ubuntu on a USB like Tails OS but without the TOR Network

Tags: boot, networking, usb, tor

I installed tails on a USB and everything was great but when I tried to browse the web, I get it is anonymous but it makes it slower than normal to load websites or videos online. The point is I want to run Ubuntu live on ram but also with persistent live and to be able to install new apps. I also already tried installing it on a USB but it takes too long to boot up and it is so slow. Somebody help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I boot a Live USB fully to RAM, allowing me to remove the disk?](https://askubuntu.com/q/829917/) and [How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot a live Ubuntu system to RAM with the boot option `toram`, but if you want persistence, the partition for persistence cannot be in RAM. It will still be quite responsive (after a slow start).

I suggest that you use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) (mkusb-dus) in order to create a system, that can run either as a 'standard' persistent live system or 'to RAM'.

See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10) and links from it.

Comment: I tried this but it just showed Try Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu when I boot it up. Trying it again tho, thanks for answering.

Comment: This kinda worked but how do I install programs on it permanently.

Comment: Did you select 'Persistent live' in mkusb-dus? In that case there should be several options (not only Try Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu). Or did you use mkusb-plug, which is a simpler method? I'd recommend mkusb-dus in this case. -- When you have booted into a persistent live session, you install program packages like you would do into an installed Ubuntu system: `sudo add-apt-repository universe` ; `sudo apt update` ; `sudo apt install program-package-name` (for example with a small program package for the tool `htop`: `sudo apt install htop`). The package may have another name than the program.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried installing another program and it worked perfectly and is persistent. Thank y'all.

Comment: @Aim4Me, You are welcome and good luck with your persistent live system. Please remember [backup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data), if there are things that you don't want to lose.